# Python + PostgreSQL + Regex - Double Backslash Issue

Tags: python, postgresql

I am trying to query a PostgreSQL DB from python using PostgreSQL Regex.

I have a list of keywords with which I have to query some columns and extract only the values which contain the exact matches of used keywords.

Example : I want to extract all values that use "pi".
Values like "spider", "pie" should not be extracted.
Values like "pi", "delta pi", "Pi number" should be extracted.

My issue is that the \ isn't escaped when using the query.

```
keywords = [r"\y" + "something" + r"\y", r"\y" + "something1" + r"\y"]
data =  pd.read_sql_query(f""" select * from table t
                          where lower(t.description) ~ any (array[{keywords}]) or
                          lower(t.name) ~ any (array[{keywords}]) or
                          lower(t."ingredientsText") ~ any (array[{keywords}])""", conn)
```

Generating an error mid query shows what is being sent to the DB:

```
where lower(d.description) ~ any (array[['\\ysomething\\y', '\\ysomething1\\y']]) or
      lower(d.name) ~ any (array[['\\ysomething\\y', '\\ysomething1\\y']]) or
      lower(d."text") ~ any (array[['\\ysomething\\y', '\\ysomething1\\y']])
```

which doesn't return results.

Anyone has any idea how I can create a query like :

```
where lower(d.description) ~ any (array[['\ysomething\y', '\ysomething1\y']]) or
      lower(d.name) ~ any (array[['\ysomething\\y', '\ysomething1\y']]) or
      lower(d."text") ~ any (array[['\ysomething\y', '\ysomething1\y']])
```

Any idea on how to solve this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for you time.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone bumping into a similar issue, I have resolved my issue by using bracket expressions instead of regex.

I substituated :

```
keywords = [r"\y" + "something" + r"\y", r"\y" + "something1" + r"\y"]
```

with :

```
keywords = [r"[[:<:]]{}[[:>:]]".format(i.lower()) for i in keywords if i]
```